# Adding object to supertest

Tags: node.js, express, testing, supertest

I'm trying to test one of my routes, which would usually expect an object on the request object (e.g. req.exampleData = { }).

I've tried looking for examples, but I've only found .set which attaches to the req header.

Ideally, I would want something like:

`await request(app)
.get('/api/testRoute)
.attach('exampleData', { })`

Is such a thing possible for supertest?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Any solution in here?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can use `field` as in

```
await request(app)
.get('/api/testRoute)
.field('exampleData', {})
```

on your server

```
req.body.exampleData // {}
```

Comment: op is asking how to add exampleData to the req object not to its body.